# Clean up VBA search

Tags: vba, excel

I have code that is identical minus two changes that would happen each time, which I can use variable for, but I don't want to use a bunch of `if` statements.

```
C = 1
fnd = Sheet1.Cells(C, 8)
While InStr(fnd, "Customer Name:") <= 0 And C <= 300
C = C + 1
fnd = Sheet1.Cells(C, 8)
Wend
If C >= 300 Then
Sheet2.Cells(r, 2) = "Not found"
Else
cleanup = InStr(1, fnd, ": ")
finalString = Right(fnd, Len(fnd) - cleanup - 1)
Sheet2.Cells(r, 2) = finalString
End If
```

What would be changing is where it says "Customer Name" would have to go through 8 other variables, at this point, and the constant number that's in the `sheet.cells` line would need to increase by one each time.

I know I can just use a counter and increase that counter for the column number in sheet 2 each time the block of code runs, but as far as making Customer Name change to customer email, customer points, etc, I'm not sure how to use a variable for that without doing it the long (and probably wrong) way of

```
If i=1 then
sch="Customer Name"
Elseif i=2 then
sch="Customer Email"
```

and on and on down the list.

Right now I have that original block of code showing up 8 times, and only those two things are changing, so it's really a waste of storage space (not that it's really anything noticeable), so I'm thinking there has to be a better way than how I have it or setting it up with a bunch of `If`/`Then` statements.

Comment: We all want to clean up our code and make it more readable. To make your title more unique, try to let it say what your code is about, not what kind of answers you are looking for.

Comment: It will be better to include a bigger piece of your program, so that we can better see its overall structure and methods. Good answers will likely involve some restructuring and alternative/better method decomposition in order to reduce the duplicated logic.

Comment: Are these variables declared anywhere? Are you using `Option Explicit`? Is this code in a `Sub` or in a `Function`? Is that procedure doing more than just that? Please include more of the context around the specific code you're interested in improving - don't worry about making a long post, this site is quite different from Stack Overflow where they like everything boiled-down and examplified.

Comment: The desire to improve code is implied for all questions on this site. Question titles should reflect the purpose of the code, not how you wish to have it reworked. See [ask].

Answer (score 4):

Your looping code can be made smoother and more efficient. Try this instead. It sets the range to check from the beginning, and lets you use a string array named `CustomerFields` for your Customer Name, Customer E-mail, etc.:

```
For Loop1 = LBound(CustomerFields) to UBound(CustomerFields)
    With Sheet1
        Set Range1 = .Range(.Cells(1, 8), .Cells(300, 8)
        For Each Cell1 in Range1
            If InStr(1, Cell1.Value, CustomerFields(Loop1), vbtextcompare) > 0 Then
                cleanup = InStr(1, Cell1.Value, ":")
                finalString = Right(Cell1.Value, Len(Cell1.Value) - cleanup - 1)
                Sheet2.Cells(r, 2) = finalString
            End If
        Next Cell1
    End With
Next Loop1
```

Answer (score 4):

You'll have to either manually type a list of terms into VBA, or have them written in a sheet and pull them into an array/collection. Assuming the former: I'd have a separate procedure like so:

```
Public Sub FillSearchStrings(ByRef arrayList As Variant)

    Dim ix As Long
        ix = 0

    arrayList = Array()

    ix = ix + 1
    ReDim Preserve arrayList(1 to ix)
    arrayList(ix) = "Customer Name"

    ix = ix + 1
    ReDim Preserve arrayList(1 to ix)
    arrayList(ix) = "Customer Email"

    ...

End Sub
```

So you'll always know where to go if you need to change it.

Then you call it from your main procedure like so:

```
Dim searchStrings As Variant

    FillSearchStrings searchStrings
```

And then we determine the size of our list, and iterate over it like so:

```
Dim LB1 As Long, UB1 As Long
    LB1 = LBound(searchStrings)
    UB1 = UBound(searchStrings)

Dim ix As Long, searchTerm As String

    For ix = LB1 To UB1

    searchTerm = searchStrings(ix)

    ...
```

Now, for your looping, I'd recommend putting your column in an array first (best practice for **all** static spreadsheet data) and then looping through your array:

```
Dim sheetData As Variant
    sheetData = Array()

Dim dataCol As Long
    dataCol = ix + 7

Dim dataRange As Range
    Set dataRange = Range(Cells(1, dataCol), Cells(300, dataCol))

    sheetData = dataRange ' now sheetdata(1) = row 1 etc.

    Dim iy As Long, stringToSearch As String
    Dim matchIsFound As Boolean, matchPosition As Long

    matchIsFound = False
    iy = LBound(sheetData) + 1
    Do While iy <= UBound(sheetData) And matchIsFound = False

        stringToSearch = CStr(sheetData(iy)) ' converts our data to string form
        matchPosition = InStr(1, stringToSearch, searchTerm, vbTextCompare) 'vbBinaryCompare for case-Sensitive comparison
        If matchPosition > 1 Then matchIsFound = True

        iy = iy + 1

    Loop
```

Now, we can easily add terms, modify our targeted ranges, add new behaviour etc. and the code will automatically adjust. Plus, it's much clearer what everything is doing.